# PowerShell to get the city name and person’s name from the Managedby property in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

Can anyone help me with this please. I need to derive a City name and person’s full name from the `managedby` property in Active Directory which, looks like this:

```
CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com
```

So I need to take everything out and be left with "`Marley, Bob PARIS`"

I can get the Paris bit out but not the full name:

This produces `Paris` in the output:

```
CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' | %{(($_ -split ',')[-3] -split '=')[1]}
```

Can anyone help me extract the full name too?

Comment: I don't knwo what command got you that output, but try `<command> | select 'name', 'city'` or something similar to that

Comment: Hi Neko, the string is 'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' which is piped through the foreach-object loop to strip out the non-required chracters, which is this case produces "Paris"

Comment: Have you considered making this a json file or variable? It would make it a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

You can split a DistinguishedName into its separate RDN (RelativeDistinguishedName) components and then choose the parts you need from that.

```
'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -split ',\s*(?<!\\,\s*)'
```

would return

```
CN=Marley\, Bob
OU=Users
OU=PARIS
DC=Domain
DC=com
```

In your case you could use that like:

```
$rdn = 'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -split ',\s*(?<!\\,\s*)'
'{0} {1}' -f (($rdn[0] -split '=')[1] -replace '\\'), (($rdn[2] -split '=')[1])
```

Returns

> Marley, Bob PARIS

However, **this will ONLY work if all locations are stored in the first sub OU inside the `Users` OU..**

---

You could also use the regex `-replace` if you insist on trying this in a one-liner:

```
'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' -replace '\\' -replace 'CN=(.+),OU=.+OU=(.+)(,DC=.*){2,}$', '$1 $2'
```

It captures the first occurrence op `CN=` which **must** be followed by `,OU=` in backreference 1 (`$1`).
Next it captures the second occurrence of `OU=` which **must** be followed by `,DC=` in backreference 2 (`$2`).

In short: if ever your OU structure changes this will NOT work anymore!

Comment: Thanks Theo, that works in two lines, the second line delivering the desired output. I will try to stitch it together.  Thanks!

Comment: @IanB Although I would not recommend it really, because DNs can have MANY parts, I have added a one-liner alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks Theo! That works perfectly! I get your point about if the OU structure changing too.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you can extract the city and name of the string, of course

```
'CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com' | %{(($_ -split ',OU',2)[0] -split '=')[1] -replace '\\'}
```

but as it is the distinguishedname of an object I think it would be better to retrieve that object in AD to get that information

```
$DN="CN=Marley\, Bob,OU=Users,OU=PARIS,DC=Domain,DC=com"
$object = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry "LDAP://$DN"
$name=$object.Properties.cn
$city=$object.Properties.l
```

Comment: Thanks Mikel, the use case is a one-liner with a single pass in AD. The only property of the computer object that gives location and the user's name is ManagedBy so I was hoping to extract both ciry and full name from that by removing the other characters.